# syntax issue using object operator

Tags: php

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '->' (T_OBJECT_OPERATOR) in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\sms\index.php on line 6

```
1 <?php
   2 require("class-Clockwork.php");
   3 $apikey="5170eaee591186334af99549a";
   4 $clockwork=new Clockwork($apikey);
   5 $message=array('to' => '+251978976', 'message'=> 'This is test text message');
   6 $done=Clockwork->send($message);
   7 ?>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
- $done=Clockwork->send($message);
+ $done=$clockwork->send($message);
```